# how to clip a larger width fixed table in div within its container div

Tags: jquery, html, css

so i need to position fixed a tr to freeze when scroll down, all worked and lovely but the TR i am freezing is overflowing on the page and going out of the table

i created a container with fixed width  but i cannot get the table to only show as much as the container width

this is a basic example if anyone can help

```css
body{
  height: 900px;
}

.fixedhead{
  background:red;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.container{
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixedhead">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Some very long text here,</td>
        <td>bigger than the container div</td>
        <td>but it should only show as much as the container div</td>
        <td>and still be fixed to the top</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>bla</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
  </div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<div class="container blue">
it should only show upto here
</div>
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Just Provide `width` to `.fixedhead` and provide `overflow-x:auto`. It should work as expected

Comment: thank you, but i need it to scroll within the container
i am using jquery to change position left of the fixedhead so it moves left and right but within the container , i want container to work more like a window but the fixedhead inside scroll right and left using jquery.css

style="position: relative; left: 85px;" <-controlled by jquery

Comment: use "!important" for the position if you always want position:fixed